# Fluid layout with margin-bottom and nested div 100% height issues

Tags: html, height, fluid-layout, css

I'm in the process of transforming an existing fixed layout to be "fluid".

I've got 2 issues:

1. When `#content` contains a lot of data, which makes it expand over the viewport I can't find a way to have a margin at the bottom.
2. The `#content` seems to "loose" it's height when `position:relative;` is added, which is necessary to place `#content` on to of `#topgradient`. I need `#test` (blue border) to fill `#content` and `#content` needs to fill `#contentwrapper`.

I've got an existing fixed layout which works great, the issues began after I added/changed `height: auto; min-height: 100%;` on the divs.

See this sort of messy/prototyping jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bQeu3/2/ (click in the white area (`#content`) to change content)

The optimal solution on issue 1 would look like:
[image: Optimal solution on issue 1]

The optimal solution on issue 2 would look like:
[image: Optimal solution on issue 2]

Hope you can help?

Answer (score 0):

for the first question:
http://jsfiddle.net/bQeu3/7/

remove `height:100%` from #page

add `padding:1px` to #page

add `margin-bottom:100px` to #contentwrapper

to keep the size of #contentwrapper when you clicked something:

```
#test{
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

you might need to correct the 300px considering borders and such...

Comment: It does fix the margins, but `#page` needs to be 100% in the height.

Comment: The layout in the second screen shot needs to be retained thus the 100% height.